# send picture as an attachment via SMS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to send a picture via an iphone app.

How to send the picture as an attachment with the SMS?
How to do that programatically?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to send picture  via sms with MFMessageComposeViewController, You could send however a picture SMS, (the stuff like an emoticon) but your provider will need to support binary sms.

Answer (score 0):

1st a picture will be via MMS, not SMS.
Now, unfortunately I do not know exactly how to do this with images, but I have done it with text before using the "MFMessageComposeViewController" method... I'm sure with google you can find your answer, Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only the  recipients and the body can be prepopulated.
You may like to see the [ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Thanks!